# Missing branches on TFS Integration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I've been using the TFS Integration service to move our main set of projects from Scrum from Team System (I know, I know) on TFS 2010 to Microsoft Agile 5.0 on the same server.  All work items have transferred fine and I've spent the last week migrating VC items.  The service claims everything is migrated but I'm missing a good dozen branches and no matter how many times I restart I can't get it to migrate the rest.

What are my options?  Do I have to destroy the new project and start from scratch or will a new integration do it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" UniqueId="4a01478e-1ba7-4c62-8925-714739e1fab6" FriendlyName="TFS to TFS Version Control and Work Item Tracking with Links">
  <Providers>
    <Provider ReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a" FriendlyName="TFS 2010 Migration VC Provider" />
    <Provider ReferenceName="04201d39-6e47-416f-98b2-07f0013f8455" FriendlyName="TFS 2010 Migration WIT Provider" />
  </Providers>
  <Addins />
  <SessionGroup CreationTime="2013-09-24T11:28:46.567+01:00" FriendlyName="TFS to TFS Version Control and Work Item Tracking with Links" SessionGroupGUID="a3d4e2fe-3b6c-4d20-a9c3-e5adf35567bb" Creator="MDLIMITED\damien.ryan" SyncIntervalInSeconds="0" SyncDurationInMinutes="0">
    <MigrationSources>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="ea1112aa-8b29-4249-b5ad-a56d9e3d4cde" FriendlyName="<SERVER> (VC)" ServerIdentifier="b0584010-6dfd-4ecd-95b5-f7bacdfcf0d7" ServerUrl="http://<SERVER>:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" SourceIdentifier="RCM" ProviderReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317" FriendlyName="<SERVER> (VC)" ServerIdentifier="b0584010-6dfd-4ecd-95b5-f7bacdfcf0d7" ServerUrl="http://<SERVER>:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" SourceIdentifier="RCM_Platform" ProviderReferenceName="febc091f-82a2-449e-aed8-133e5896c47a">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="38c2d113-700b-4bc6-ab36-a3c304ac8bc3" FriendlyName="<SERVER> (WIT)" ServerIdentifier="b0584010-6dfd-4ecd-95b5-f7bacdfcf0d7" ServerUrl="http://<SERVER>:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" SourceIdentifier="RCM" ProviderReferenceName="04201d39-6e47-416f-98b2-07f0013f8455">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
      <MigrationSource InternalUniqueId="089ca660-2cd3-4a25-a0ae-ad0d9004723c" FriendlyName="<SERVER> (WIT)" ServerIdentifier="b0584010-6dfd-4ecd-95b5-f7bacdfcf0d7" ServerUrl="http://<SERVER>:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" SourceIdentifier="RCM_Platform" ProviderReferenceName="04201d39-6e47-416f-98b2-07f0013f8455">
        <Settings>
          <Addins />
          <UserIdentityLookup />
          <DefaultUserIdProperty UserIdPropertyName="DisplayName" />
        </Settings>
        <CustomSettings />
        <StoredCredential />
      </MigrationSource>
    </MigrationSources>
    <Sessions>
      <Session CreationTime="2013-09-24T11:28:46.557+01:00" SessionUniqueId="2325d8e9-ed67-473d-acd8-86301e867ec6" FriendlyName="Version Control Session" LeftMigrationSourceUniqueId="ea1112aa-8b29-4249-b5ad-a56d9e3d4cde" RightMigrationSourceUniqueId="9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317" SessionType="VersionControl">
        <EventSinks />
        <CustomSettings>
          <SettingXml />
          <SettingXmlSchema />
        </CustomSettings>
        <Filters>
          <FilterPair Neglect="false">
            $/<FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="ea1112aa-8b29-4249-b5ad-a56d9e3d4cde" FilterString="<FROMPROJ> />
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317" FilterString="<TOPROJ>" />
          </FilterPair>
          <FilterPair Neglect="true">
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="ea1112aa-8b29-4249-b5ad-a56d9e3d4cde" FilterString="$/RCM/BuildProcessTemplates" />
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317" FilterString="<TOPROJ>/BuildProcessTemplates" />
          </FilterPair>
        </Filters>
      </Session>
      <Session CreationTime="2013-09-24T11:28:46.567+01:00" SessionUniqueId="2f6ea511-a24a-4e09-9166-dc9c45a4b7be" FriendlyName="Work Item Tracking Session" LeftMigrationSourceUniqueId="38c2d113-700b-4bc6-ab36-a3c304ac8bc3" RightMigrationSourceUniqueId="089ca660-2cd3-4a25-a0ae-ad0d9004723c" SessionType="WorkItemTracking">
        <EventSinks />
        <CustomSettings>
          <SettingXml>
            <WITSessionCustomSetting>
              <Settings />
              <WorkItemTypes>
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Bug" RightWorkItemTypeName="Bug" fieldMap="BugToBug" />
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Sprint Backlog Item" RightWorkItemTypeName="Task" fieldMap="SBIToTask" />
                <WorkItemType LeftWorkItemTypeName="Product Backlog Item" RightWorkItemTypeName="User Story" fieldMap="PBIToUserStory" />
              </WorkItemTypes>
              <FieldMaps>
                <FieldMap name="BugToBug">
                  <MappedFields>
                    <MappedField LeftName="*" RightName="*" MapFromSide="Left" valueMap="" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.EstimatedEffort" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.WorkRemaining" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.Build.Environment" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.TestingImpact" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DateDiscovered" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DateClosed" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.Team" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.BusinessPriority" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DeliveryOrder" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.HistoryDate" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.ReplicationActionDetail" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                  </MappedFields>
                  <AggregatedFields />
                  <UserIdentityFields>
                    <LeftUserIdentityFields />
                    <RightUserIdentityFields />
                  </UserIdentityFields>
                </FieldMap>
                <FieldMap name="SBIToTask">
                  <MappedFields>
                    <MappedField LeftName="*" RightName="*" MapFromSide="Left" valueMap="" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.EstimatedEffort" RightName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.WorkRemaining" RightName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.Team" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.HistoryDate" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.TaskPriority" RightName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" MapFromSide="Left" />
                  </MappedFields>
                  <AggregatedFields />
                  <UserIdentityFields>
                    <LeftUserIdentityFields />
                    <RightUserIdentityFields />
                  </UserIdentityFields>
                </FieldMap>
                <FieldMap name="PBIToUserStory">
                  <MappedFields>
                    <MappedField LeftName="*" RightName="*" MapFromSide="Left" valueMap="" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.EstimatedEffort" RightName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.WorkRemaining" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.Team" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.BusinessPriority" RightName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.DeliveryOrder" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.HistoryDate" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                    <MappedField LeftName="Conchango.TeamSystem.Scrum.ConditionsOfAcceptance" RightName="" MapFromSide="Left" />
                  </MappedFields>
                  <AggregatedFields />
                  <UserIdentityFields>
                    <LeftUserIdentityFields />
                    <RightUserIdentityFields />
                  </UserIdentityFields>
                </FieldMap>
              </FieldMaps>
              <ValueMaps />
            </WITSessionCustomSetting>
          </SettingXml>
          <SettingXmlSchema />
        </CustomSettings>
        <Filters>
          <FilterPair Neglect="false">
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="38c2d113-700b-4bc6-ab36-a3c304ac8bc3" FilterString="[System.AreaPath] UNDER '<AREAPATH>/>'" />
            <FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="089ca660-2cd3-4a25-a0ae-ad0d9004723c" FilterString="[System.Id] = 0" />
          </FilterPair>
        </Filters>
      </Session>
    </Sessions>
    <Linking>
      <CustomSettings />
      <LinkTypeMappings />
    </Linking>
    <WorkFlowType Frequency="ContinuousManual" DirectionOfFlow="Unidirectional" SyncContext="Disabled" />
    <CustomSettings />
    <UserIdentityMappings EnableValidation="false">
      <UserIdentityLookupAddins />
    </UserIdentityMappings>
    <ErrorManagement>
      <ErrorRouters />
      <ReportingSettings />
    </ErrorManagement>
  </SessionGroup>
</Configuration>
```

Edit: Added a selection from the log to show that changesets are being analyzed, migration instructions created, but not committed.

I added the MergeScope parameters as you suggested and there was no change in how the application worked.

If you look at the logs, it tries to pend operations against later changesets, but these operations are never commited to TFS:

```
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Starting analysis of TFS change 78046 
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Created 1 actions for TFS change 78046 
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Analyzing TFS change 78124 : 24/24 
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Starting analysis of TFS change 78124 
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Created 1 actions for TFS change 78124 
[16/10/2013 17:34:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Generating migration instructions for the migration source 9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317
```

...

```
[16/10/2013 17:47:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Generating migration instruction for ChangeGroup 1922014 
[16/10/2013 17:47:22] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Starting basic conflict detection 
[16/10/2013 17:47:56] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Finishing basic conflict detection 
[16/10/2013 17:47:56] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Loading 50 ChangeGroup(s) 
[16/10/2013 17:47:56] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Post-processing delta table entries from the migration source 9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317 
[16/10/2013 17:47:56] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Marking as 'DeltaComplete' the target-side delta table for uni-directional session 
[16/10/2013 17:47:57] TfsIntegrationService.exe Information: 0 : VersionControl: Migrating to the migration source 9f1fc9e6-6a37-4c2e-9ca8-336897850317
```

Answer (score 2):

@Gutwulf, are you seeing any exceptions, warnings or messages in your log files that ralate to the branches you are missing? Can you share the configuration and logfiles? If urgent, consider raising a support call as outlined in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/06/06/toc-tfs-integration-tools-blog-posts-and-reference-sites.aspx.

Comment: When I look at the missing branches in the log, it says it's pending a bunch of changes and analyzing the correct changeset numbers.  Can't see any exceptions though.  The configuration itself is the standard VC to VC section with any rules added as conflicts are found.

Comment: Just had a look through the migrated changesets and it looks like they stop at around April of 2011, which explains the missing branches.  Is it safe to set up another migration of VC to VC to force the rest through?

Comment: Any indication as to why the migration stopped on April 2011? There must be a reason logged if the tool stopped. Are there any conflicts? If yes, the VC migration will stop until they are resolved ... after which you can re-run the same session and it will pickup at the point it left off.

Comment: I had a look at the Sync Point table and it claims the HWMark for VC is 42860, which matches up with changes around that time.  In the logs, the analysis generates migrations for changes after that, but no migrations take place.  I remember the service crashed so does that mean everything should be re-run, or is there a way to force a re-analysis?

Comment: Re-running the migration session will restart from the high-water mark and resume, unless there is a version control conflict. Are you sure there are no conflicts showing up in the admin UI under runtime or session conflicts? I would need to look at the log file to dig into possible causes.

Comment: I've added a selection from the log file to try and explain what I mean.  I don't mind sending on the whole log, but 38Mb of text would probably be frowned upon ;-)  Thanks for being so patient with me Willy.